# How to implement upgrade/versioning for interfaces declared with Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE?

Tags: c++, qt, abstract-class

Qt contains examples of how to implement a basic plugin using `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` with some versioned string as in

```
class MyBaseClass {
public:
    virtual void myMethod() = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(MyBaseClass, "MyBaseClass/v1.0")
```

with the plugin being

```
class ActualPlugin: public QObject, public MyBaseClass {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "MyBaseClass/v1.0")
    Q_INTERFACES(MyBaseClass)

public:
    virtual void myMethod() override { /*....*/ }
};
```

and the client code loads this plugin using:

```
QPluginLoader loader("/path/to/plugin/file");
QObject *plugin = loader->instance();
MyBaseClass *actualPlugin = qobject_cast<MyBaseClass *>(plugin);
if (actualPlugin != nullptr) {
    // do something with actualPlugin
}
```

How to use this functionality to add new members to the class (say, upgraded version `MyBaseClass2`) and to use them in a backward-compatible way?

```
class MyBaseClass2 {
public:
    // changed myMethod() from MyBaseClass
    virtual bool myMethod(int parameter) = 0;
    virtual void anotherMethod() = 0;
};
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(MyBaseClass2, "MyBaseClass/v2.0")
```

So that now `ActualPlugin` will inherit from `MyBaseClass2` and loading code will distinguish interfaces between `"..v1.0"` and `"..v2.0"`?

Does the upgraded plugin need to have 2 `Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE` statements or only the upgraded one? Should the new class `MyBaseClass2` be rather a parent of the old class or a separate one?

Comment: Questions like this are generally easier to answer, if you provide a [mcve] type code, or in this case just relevant snippets (just be sure it's real snippets), at least minimal plugin header, and the plugin loading code. That way answer can show how to change your code, instead of needing to write all the code in the answer.

Comment: @hyde this question is rather an ask to showcase a minimal reproducible example which is missing in Qt documentation